# C++: Reverse the lines in a text file using stack

Tags: c++, text, stack, reverse, lines

I have this code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main () {


ifstream in;
in.open("example.txt");

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("out.txt");

stack<string> lines;
string temp;
while(getline(in, temp))
    lines.push(temp);
while(!lines.empty())
    outfile << lines.pop() << endl;

in.close();
outfile.close();

return 0;
}
```

My question is, why did i get a compile error of "no match for operator << in outfile".

Comment: Extra credit - how well does this code work if your file has 100M lines?

Comment: HA, not homework. I have a .bmp that i converted to binary but it was upside down. I just needed to flip it before i start to convert the binary into hex and then put that into an array for the screen the image goes on. small screen so efficiency doesnt matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`pop()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) returns `void`, not a `std::string`. Use [`top()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top) and then `pop()`:

```
while(!lines.empty())
{
    outfile << lines.top() << endl;
    lines.pop();
}
```

Comment: AHHH, thanks. So i changed it to lines.top() and then i lines.pop() after that.